# Android. StartActivityForResult

Tags: android, kotlin

Имеется Fragment из которого я хочу запустить activity и получить из нее результат.

Запускаю так:

```
 val intent = Intent(it, PaymentActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("amount", dot.revenue.toString())
    intent.putExtra("id", currentDid)
    startActivityForResult(intent, SUCCESS_PAYMENT)
```

Пытаюсь получить во Fragment:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == SUCCESS_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Оплата прошла успешно", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                currentDid?.let {
                    viewModel.getDot(currentDid!!)
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Оплата не прошла", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
```

Activity, к которой принадлежит этот фрагмент

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
```

Запускаемая Activity

```
if(paymentResultContext.getDeferredData() == null){
            dismiss()
            saveCheck(paymentResultContext, did);

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            mActivity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            mActivity.finish();
        }
        else{
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            mActivity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
            mActivity.finish();
        }
```

Но Toast после завершения Activity не срабатывает

**Update.** Повесил Log на onActivityResult в MainActivity
Прилетает

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        Log.d("requestCode", requestCode.toString())
        Log.d("resultCode", resultCode.toString())
        if(data != null){
            Log.d("data", data.toString())
        }
        else{
            Log.d("data", "null")
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
```

Comment: А у вас, случаем, не используется богомерзкая навигация от гугла из JetPack? Коли да, то надо, вроде, вручную рекурсивно по фрагментам пробежать и вручную onActivityResult вызвать.

Comment: Просто уберите переопределение onActivityResult из активити. В этом случае сработает коллбек во фрагменте.

Comment: Стало отрабатывать, по какой причине не работало, не пойму, вроде ничего не делал